# 2 questions About C# WinForms and MySql database Search

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4

Hello I have a project about searching Mysql database with a C# Winform on Visual Studio 2010(Teacher's orders). I have to make use of Entity Framework to make the connection but the query criteria doesn't work. Below is a portion of my code that just gives me more errors by the second. Not only that I cannot seem to display the desired result to the datagridview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stuguiEntities sqlcmd = new stuguiEntities();


        if (ID.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            double id = Convert.ToDouble(ID.Text);
            var query = from i in sqlcmd.table.First(s =>s.id == id) select i;

        }

        else
        {
            if (Name.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                var query = from i in sqlcmd.table.First(s=>s.NAME==Name ) select i;
            }
           // there are 4 more if statements like the above 
         }
         gridview.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

My problem ; as most of you probably guessed; is inside the lambda expression. I don't know how I'm gonna make that boolean check anymore. I'm getting in the ID part ***Select not found** error. If I don't I will get **Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' ***  error.

Any tip will be appreciated.

Comment: If `Name` is a `TextBox`, you maybe meant `s => s.NAME == Name.Text` inside that lambda function?

Comment: Next is _query_ not defined right?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt; taht method gives me _Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Student Gui.table'. 'Select' not found._ error.  @Steve yeah but I don't  know how to define it, moronic as it is. I have researched many books about the subject on the net and from the schools library but they weren't much help.

Comment: I'm having even trouble understand the query. You're already using a LINQ query with `First()` that gives you the first object for which the predicate is true. Is your intent to only return the first one? Did you mean a `WHERE` clause in the style of `var query = from s in sqlcmd.table where s.NAME == Name.Text select s;`? For the "moving it out of the scope": Visual Studio tells you the type of the variable when you hover over its name. Then just write `<ThatType> query = null;` over the first `if` to delcare that variable.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, I'm ashamed to not even looking what was before me. Thank you.  Now if I can just return the result.

Comment: I have fixed the code.